# resolve different java and javac version in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

My `java --version` gives:

```
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.21.10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.21.10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

But when I do: `javac --version` I get:

```
javac 17
```

whereis java gives:

```
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /opt/jdk-17/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

As far as I can remember I downloaded openjdk 17 from the official site and followed official documentation.

I usually work with maven projects and I just noticed this issue. Haven't created any problem so far. But I would like to resolve it. Is it possible to do so without removing java and reinstalling?

Update:

```
echo $PATH
/home/arnob/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/jdk-17/bin:/home/arnob/sdks/flutter/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/home/arnob/.local/bin:/home/arnob/.pub-cache/bin:/usr/lib/postgres/13/bin
```

And

```
ls -l /usr/bin/java

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Dec 19 00:58 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

Comment: Please show the output of `echo $PATH` and `ls -l /usr/bin/java`

Comment: Hi, I have added both the outputs you requested

Comment: What is the output of `update-alternatives --display java` and `update-alternatives --display javac`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bashrc, for example, seems like you're adding `/opt/jdk-17/bin` to the PATH, but at the end, not before `/usr/bin/`, and you have Java 11 JRE installed separately, so it gets picked up first

You should fix this by reversing it

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-17
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH"
```

I suggest doing the same thing for flutter, maven, Postgres, etc

Comment: As per your suggestion this worked: `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$FLUTTER_HOME:$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PROTOC:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin:$POSTGRES:$PATH"`

Answer (score 0):

Run the below commands in your terminal and choose the default java and javac version. You needn't uninstall anything.

```
update-alternatives --config java
update-alternatives --config javac
```